# InfoPath 2010 field validation in repeating section

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

I would like to put simple validation when check box is checked it should make one of the field mandatory to fill.Here is my form,

[image]

All checkboxes are bind with "Control1" Question section and the field I want to validate is bind with "Value" of Answers section. Problem is whatever condition I write it's getting repeated for all the check boxes. For example, All the check boxes has some unique id like QUE1 so even if I would like to use unique id on check boxes it's not working because same is applying to all the check boxes.

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to think about normalising your data and the layout. Repeating sections will not achieve what you describe. At the least you would need a repeating table, where properties are assigned on a row by row basis.

Comment: @teylyn, Can this same form design using repeating table with same fields structure ?

Comment: It's hard to tell. With field names like these it is impossible to guess what you want to achieve. Step back and do some data architecture first, then design the form.